# REACT - What's the best way to keep text formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text, ms-word, formatting

In a word document I have some text with exponent. I would like to know if there's any possibility to copy and paste the text with exponent in a Text Input of ReactJS and keep the text formatting.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't just copy and paste some word formatted output and paste it into a textarea / text input.

Scientists are usually working with `latex` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX, so they did, before there were MS Word.

However, there are libraries which you can use to render the latex format into the DOM. like https://www.mathjax.org/

There are also React Components as Wrappers for MathJax https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax

This libraries will parse the latex input and create a styled output so it looks like in MSWord

However, if you just need the square² this is how you can write it `234&sup2;`

Comment: Do you have a lib for react native?

Comment: However you could use a webview